# Set input mask inside modal using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to mask input only if some values a selected from drop down list. I managed to call javascript function form code behind which will call jquery. When I am displaying alert it works fine. When I am trying to mask input (after modal is load and value is selected from drop-down) my modal disappears and I can't click anywhere.

Input fields which needs to be masked:

```html
<input id="txt_debtor_phone" name="txt_debtor_phone" placeholder="Phone" class="form-control txt_debtor_phone frm_debtor_request" runat="server" />
```

Calling JS function from code behind when condition is met:

```cs
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.Page.GetType(), "mask_phone_number", "javascript:mask_phone_number();", true);
```

JS function inside modal:

```
function mask_phone_number() {
            jqueryfunction("I am here");
            //alert("hello");
        }
```

jQuery function inside modal:

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
            jqueryfunction = function (test) {
               // alert(test);
                $('input[name=txt_debtor_phone]').mask('000-000-000');
            }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Change .modal-backdrop class property to display none